# Formatting dataframes for statistical analyses

Tags: r, dataframe, anova

What I would like to do is to test the statistical relationship between one response and one explanatory variable. To do this, I assumed a one-way ANOVA was an effective procedure. However, my dataframe is not set up to do this. I have one column for a response variable (df1) but several columns that would be categorised into the explanatory variable I want (df2 and df3) below. As a crude example, df2 and df3 represent a season (summer) in 2 seperate locations. How would I test the influence of summer on the response variable in this instance?

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1000, 36*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:500, 36*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
df3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:200, 36*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
Example <- cbind(df1,df2,df3)
```

Would this involve restructuring the dataframe so that df2 and df3 merge to become one long column and double the length of df1?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Sounds to me that you need a regression instead of anova

Comment: As @Jaap said, this sounds like a linear regression problem. via something like this `lm(V1~V1.1+V1.2,data=Example)` if you changed `cbind` to `data.frame()`

Comment: Of course you can `cbind` in a data frame two columns (with one long two times the other one) but the shorter will be recycled. Consider this example : `col1 <- 1:3; col2 <- rnorm(6); dat <- cbind(col1, col2)`. I don't really think that is what you want.

Comment: Thank you Japp and Andrew for the comments.
SabDeM is there a way to line up the columns in this way. I.e. to unite df2 and df3 as one long column before using cbind function to recycle the df1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Jaap and Andrew Taylor, the problem was formatting a linear regression. This was achieved through the 'stack' and 'cbind' functions.

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1000, 36*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:500, 36*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
df3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:200, 36*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
Example <- cbind(df2,df3)
Stacked <- stack(Example)
Combined <- cbind(df1,Stacked)
colnames(Combined) <- c("Response","Explanatory","Variable")
Linear <- lm(Explanatory~Response, data = Combined)
summary(Linear)
```

Stack put all the explanatory variables (df2 and df3) into one column, whilst cbind combined this new column with the values from response (df1), with these values being replicated to create a dataframe with an even number of rows, as per SabDeM's comment.